# Entity Framework namespaces - context namespace

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have an edmx file and I loaded 5 tables.
I would like to change the namespace of 2 of the 5 tables so the context object will be in another namespace.
Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Does it mean that you want to have one context for 3 tables in first namespace and another context for 2 tables in other namespace?

Answer (score 2):

Not possible through the designer [as far as I know].

Options:

- Tweak the code generation yourself ([more info here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456821.aspx))
- Use the new [EF code-first (EF 4.1)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/03/15/ef-4-1-code-first-walkthrough.aspx) approach where this should be entirely possible out of the box

Comment: you can still use code first with an existing database schema, and you also have the option to tweak the code generation yourself

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you want you need two separate EDMX files.

Comment: Is it normal to work with several edmx files and one database?

Comment: @Naor: If you want to use separate modules where each is handling its own data then it is normal.